# Linux SOCK_RAW Interface

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I am using raw socket (protocol:- ETH_P_ALL) for receiving raw packets through Ethernet interface. I am able to capture raw ethernet packets. But how other network applications like ping, DNS, etc are also receiving/capturing data while I am capturing? How can I configure it such that only I can capture data through Ethernet interface?

Comment: Are you saying, "how do I block other applications from receiving while I'm reading the ethernet port?"   If that's the case, you probably want a filter driver, not a socket.

Comment: What is filter driver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342252/how-to-filter-and-intercept-linux-packets-by-using-net-dev-add-api

Comment: Can I do like this, Running the Ethernet interface without any IP address assigned, then TCP/IP network operations will be disabled and only I will be receiving/capturing packets?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Just disable the ip addresses for that adapter.

Comment: Does it meet the following requirement completely, "Only my application can send / receive layer 2 packets through ethernet interface"?